# Alamofire not working in my project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I create  pod file in my project and opened it in workspace but my project cannot build and it has many errors
my Xcode version is 7.0.1[image]

thanks

Comment: Update to the latest version of xcode

Comment: Xcode 7.0.1 contains Swift 2.0. The latest Alamofire version requries Swift 2.2. Update your Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dan said: update Xcode (cf. Alamofire Github)

> ## Requirements
>
> - iOS 8.0+ / Mac OS X 10.9+ / tvOS 9.0+ / watchOS 2.0+
> - Xcode 7.3+

Comment: thanks for your answer.
can't use alamofire in current version anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try with specify Alamofire version on your Podfile like this: "pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'" (3.4 is version I specified)

Comment: Looking into Alamofire changelog, you could use Alamofire 3.0, maybe 3.1 or 3.2. Version 3.3 requires Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 2):

**TROUBLESHOOTING:**

1) Did you `import Alamofire` ?

2) Did you uncomment the `use_framework` line from your podfile and then do `pod install` again ?

3) Did you update to the latest version of XCode ?

---

**SOLUTION:**

The latest version of Alamofire requires the latest version of XCode !

Update to Xcode 7.3 !

---

**REFERENCE:**

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#requirements

> ## Requirements
>
> - iOS 8.0+ / Mac OS X 10.9+ / tvOS 9.0+ / watchOS 2.0+
> - Xcode 7.3+

---

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**

Use an older version of Alamofire (not recommended).

Comment: thanks for your answer.
1 and 2 are OK but my Xcode is 7.0.1 and it's not the latest version!
can't use alamofire in current version anyway?

Comment: @AmirNazari Update your XCode :) It's better anyway !

Comment: Code1000 have reason, the latest Xcode support Swift 3 syntax, and the latest Alamofire was corrected to the latest Swift 3 syntax..+1